# Can't kill Preview app

Tags: macos, crash, preview

I have strange problem, my Preview app is not responding and can't kill it.

[image]

```
leo-mac:~ leo$ sudo killall Preview
No matching processes were found
```

Force Quit button also doesn't give any result.

`ps` (and Activity Monitor) is empty:

```
leo-mac:~ leo$ ps -ax | grep -i preview
24793 ttys000    0:00.00 grep -i preview
```

It's not a zombie because next command is also empty:

`ps aux | awk '"[Zz]" ~ $8 { printf("%s, PID = %d\n", $8, $2); }'`

I really can't understand what happened. Any ideas?

Comment: Does Preview return after logging out or restarting?

Comment: Does the problem continue after quitting the Dock process?

Comment: @GrahamMiln, restarting helps me, however, I'm afraid this situation can repeat. I think problem is with some broken doc but I can't find out, which document it is.

Comment: Are any Preview.app windows visible on screen when this happens – or is it only listed in the Dock?

Comment: @GrahamMiln, only Dock. No windows, no top bar menu

Comment: Have you tried to send the kill signal (-s 9) when using kill? The normal signal tells the process to quit graceful - the KILL signal kills it. So 'kill -s9 24739' could work.

Comment: I had partial success after killing "launchservicesd".  The app would work again for the session, but a restart was still problematic and timed out.

Comment: @Redarm, problem is that `kill` can't find preview by name (No matching processes were found) and Activity Monitor is also empty. Thanks, I will try to kill `launchservicesd` in the next time

Comment: Yes, I know.  I've seen this, or similar behaviour with several different apps.   Also sometimes trying to open a recently opened document from its Dock icon, makes a pop-up appear, mentioning "The application "<app_name>" is not open any more."  Quitting 'launchservicesd' made it usable again, but it still cancelled a restart.

Comment: Just a thought: how much space (of what capacity) is free on your system disk? From my experience, low disk space tends to create strange phenomena like stuck processes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I had the same problem. Workaround:

```
sudo killall launchservicesd
sudo killall Dock
```

Answer (score 2):

It could be an issue with one of the files preview is attempting to open.

Go to

```
~/Library/Saved Application State/
```

Remove the com.Apple.Preview folder. This should resolve the issue when attempting to launch Preview after quitting the application from the above answer or shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running OS X 10.11 "El Capitan" on my Macbook Pro, and I'm experiencing this issue with Mozilla Firefox. Unfortunately, in my case the commands `sudo killall launchservicesd` and `sudo killall Dock` aren't working this problem out: after I do this, I still can't e.g. reboot the operating system.

I found that the following command works:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

**If your user account has administrative privileges on OS X**, running the above command on Terminal will force OS X to reboot. Unfortunately, this is not a solution for the issue, but as a "last resource workaround" it works like a charm.